# Wordpress get posts after certain date SQL Query issue

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

So I have a current way of getting posts:

```
<?php 
            $args2 = array('post_type' => 'attachment', 
                           'numberposts' => -1, 
                           'post_status' => null,
                           'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                           'order' => 'ASC');  
            ?>

            <?php $attachments2 = get_posts( $args2 );   ?> 

            <?php

            if ($attachments2) { ?> ...do stuff...
```

but what I need to do is only gather posts if they are published after March 1, 2012...

So I don't know how to do this - I was told to do an SQL statement but have no idea where to start.

How would you guys do this?

---

EDIT:

Here is the entire function as it stands:

```
<?php 
            $args2 = array('post_type' => 'attachment', 
                           'numberposts' => -1, 
                           'post_status' => null,
                           'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                           'order' => 'ASC');  
            ?>

            <?php $attachments2 = get_posts( $args2 );   ?> 

            <?php

            if ($attachments2) { ?>

                <h1 style='float:left'>Photos from the session</h1>

                 <?php foreach ( $attachments2 as $attachment ) {  ?>

                 <?php if( $attachment->ID != $post_thumbnail_id){ ?>

                 <div style="width:100%; height:auto;">

                 <div style="float:left; width: auto; height:auto;">

                    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' ); ?>

                    <div style="width:auto; height:49px; background-color:#FFF; display:block; width:100%; float:left; margin-bottom:15px;"><div class="floatiefooterright"></div></div>

                 </div>

                     <?php $desc = apply_filters( 'the_content', $attachment->post_content );

                         if($desc != ''){ ?>

                             <div style="width:auto; height:auto; margin:10px; display:block; float:left;">

                             <hr class="contentseperator" />

                                <?php if($desc != ''){ ?>

                                    <em><?php echo $desc ?></em>

                                <?php } ?> 

                             </div>

                         <?php } ?>

          </div>

                 <?php }; //end of the "if not featured image"?>

                 <?php }?>

           <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct, to do exactly what you want, you can't use [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).  Instead, you can use the [WP_Query class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Here is a simple example to get you started:

```
<?php

// Args
$args = array('post_type' => 'attachment', 
              'numberposts' => -1, 
              'post_status' => null,
              'post_parent' => $post->ID,
              'order' => 'ASC');


// The Query
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
    $the_query->the_post();
    // do stuff with the post here
}

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

function filter_where($where = '') {
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '2012-03-01'";
    return $where;
}
```

See [WP_Query - Time Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) for more examples.

Comment: Ok so this looks good - now what am I to do about where I previously mentioned $attachments and what not...

Comment: You can output your content where it says `// do stuff with the post here`.  `$the_query->the_post()` sets up the global post information using the [setup_postdata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) function.  Now you can use functions like [the_title()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) and the related functions at the bottom.  You can get the post ID using [the_ID()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID)

Answer (score 0):

You should use filters to do this.

```
function after_february($where = '') {
    global $wpdb;
    $where .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND post_date > %s", "2012-03-01");
    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'after_february');
$my_posts = get_posts(array('suppress_filters' => false));
remove_filter('posts_where', 'last_thirty_days');
```

Don't forget to remove the filter after your custom query.

Comment: so I have added a part to my post that shows how the function is generating HTML... do you mind going a bit more in-depth for me about this? Legend!